# Method 'Visible' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure why this is failing but for whatever reason, when the ActiveSheet is Console it fails. Going the other way, it works properly. Code is below.

```
    Sub Switch_Books()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    protect_book True

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Console" Then
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = "CDA Console" Then
                ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Else
                ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            End If
        Next ws
    Else
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = "Console" Then
                ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Else
                ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            End If
        Next ws
    End If

    protect_book False


    End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen 

Public Sub protect_book(wkbk_unlock As Boolean)

            ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="password", Structure:=True, Windows:=False
#            If wkbk_unlock Then: ThisWorkbook.Unprotect "password"

        End Sub

Comment: There must be at least one sheet visible, so if your code tries to hide the last visible sheet you'll get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
    Sub Switch_Books()
        Dim ws As Worksheet, wsName
        
        protect_book True 'This is a confusing call...
                          ' you should switch the way the boolean works 
    
        wsName = IIf(ActiveSheet.Name = "Console", "CDA Console", "Console")
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Visible = xlSheetVisible 'must be at least one sheet visible
        
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> wsName Then ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        Next ws
        
        protect_book False
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: I will take a look at the protection macro to see if there's a better way to do this. Regarding the answer, that is perfect.